# Get GUID or Native GUID from Active Directory

Tags: c#, web-services, active-directory, directoryservices

I'm writing a web service that checks if the user exists in Active Directory and if the user account is enabled. Once it checks that, I then go ahead validate their user account. Once they successfully enter username and password, I would like to get the `GUID` or `NativeGuid` for the person I'm authenticating. I would like to use `GUID` or `NativeGUID` to build a relationship inside SQL Server database.

Here's the approach I'm taking:

```
public string isAuthenticated (string serverName, string userName, string pwd)
{
    string _serverName, _userName, _pwd;
    _serverName = serverName;
    _userName = userName;
    _pwd = pwd;

    string message;

    if (DoesUserExist (_userName) == true)
    {
        if (isActive(userName) == true)
        {
            try
            {
                DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry(_serverName, _userName, _pwd);
                object nativeObject = entry.NativeObject;
                //issue is here
                string GUID = entry.Guid.ToString();
                string GUIDID = entry.NativeGuid;
                //end of issue
                message = "Successfully authenticated";
            }
            catch(DirectoryServicesCOMException ex)
            {
                    message = ex.Message;
            }
        }
        else
        {
                message = "Account is disabled";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        message = "There's an issue with your account.";
    }
    return message;      
}
```

When I try to get the `GUID` or `NativeGUID` it's returning me the same `ID` every single time for different users.

Is there a different approach I can take to get a `UNIQUE ID` for different objects in Active Directory?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're on .NET 3.5 and up, you should check out the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` (S.DS.AM) namespace. Read all about it here:

- [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx)
- [MSDN docs on System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx)

Basically, you can define a domain context and easily find users and/or groups in AD:

```
// set up domain context
using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
{
    // find a user
    UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, _userName);

    if(user != null)
    {
       // get the GUID
       var objectGuid = user.Guid;
    }
}
```

The new S.DS.AM makes it really easy to play around with users and groups in AD! I don't have an AD lying around right now to test - but I hope this will indeed give you the user object's `objectGuid`  property value.

Comment: Yes this one will work. Wanted to paste almost identical code. UPV